# Asp.net: Call to a data from a database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a database of movies, it has a columns of Title, Genere, Descreption and so on..

I basically want to have it on a gallery on my Webform (asp.net).
I have a few problems that I think about it, how can I write a code, and present it if the list is dynamically changed by the users (They insert new movies details everytime) and how can I grab it from the data base?

I will glad if you would help me.
Thanks.

(I use asp.net and sqlserver)

Comment: Have you tried the ASP.Net website? It has a range of tutorials for both Webforms and MVC that show how to connect to and consume data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select data from your table , you should use the namespaces listed below:

```
System.Data

System.Data.SqlClient
```

So to read data from tblMovie:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Intergrated Security=true;Inital Catalog='DNanme'");
cnn.open();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblName",cnn);
DataTable dt  =new DataTable();
adp.fill(dt);
cnn.Close();

//Now dt has all rows.
GridView1.Datasource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```